# Statically compile library into binary?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to [fight a really obscure](https://github.com/stepmania/stepmania/issues/1006) compilation-time bug with linking in a CMake project.

The project builds its own spin of Lua with [the following CMake file](https://github.com/stepmania/stepmania/blob/v5.0.10/extern/CMakeProject-lua.cmake):

```
set(LUA_SRC
  "lua-5.1/src/lapi.c"
   ...brevity
)

set(LUA_HPP
  "lua-5.1/src/lapi.h"
  ...brevity
)

source_group("" FILES ${LUA_SRC})
source_group("" FILES ${LUA_HPP})

add_library("lua-5.1" ${LUA_SRC} ${LUA_HPP})

set_property(TARGET "lua-5.1" PROPERTY FOLDER "External Libraries")

# include_directories(src)

if(MSVC)
  sm_add_compile_definition("lua-5.1" _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
endif(MSVC)

disable_project_warnings("lua-5.1")
```

Lua is referenced in [the main CMakeLists file](https://github.com/stepmania/stepmania/blob/v5.0.10/src/CMakeLists.txt) for compiling the resultant binary:

```
list(APPEND SMDATA_LINK_LIB
  "lua-5.1"
  ...brevity
)
...brevity
target_link_libraries("${SM_EXE_NAME}" ${SMDATA_LINK_LIB})
```

There are a few other libraries which it *does* link to which I'm okay with (like libpng, libjpeg, etc.), but I'd like Lua to be *statically* compiled into the final binary so that it has no dependencies on any system Lua.

How can I modify the CMakeLists to statically compile the Lua library into my binary?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can just tell CMake to compile the library statically:

```
add_library("lua-5.1" ${LUA_SRC} ${LUA_HPP})
```

becomes

```
add_library("lua-5.1" STATIC ${LUA_SRC} ${LUA_HPP})
```